# "Best" (idiomatic) way to select the k smallest elements from a container in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl, stl-algorithm

I find myself with this problem quite often : given a sequence, find the k-smallest element.The question is not that hard , but what i am looking for is an "idiomatic" way of doing it that is both safe (few place for error) and that communicate intent well. So end-up doing is sorting the sequence , then taking the first k element :

```cpp
std::sort(container.begin(),container.end());
std::vector<T> k_smallest(container.begin(),container.begin() + k);
```

This seems to me both safe and easy to understand, but the complexity in here is  nlogn + k, instead of just n.
How do you guys do this, is there an idomatic way (using some obscure function from  maybe) that would give the optimal complexity without having to re-implement the wheel

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[std::nth_element()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/nth_element) - linear complexity on average.

> `nth_element` is a partial sorting algorithm that rearranges elements in
>   [first, last) such that:
>
> - The element pointed at by nth is changed to whatever element would occur in that position if [first, last) was sorted.
> - All of the elements before this new nth element are less than or equal to the elements after the new nth element.

Comment: +1 It's amazing how few STL algorithms we think about using in general!

Comment: i get from the documentation that this allow me to get the k -smallest element... but how do i used this to the all the k smallest elements without getting to nlogn + k in complexity?

Comment: @GreyGeek: After using `std::nth_element` all the elements _less_ than the nth are in the range [begin, nth], they just aren't ordered. If you need them ordered you can sort that sub-range.

Comment: If you need them sorted however, you should probably use `partial_sort` to start with.

Comment: @MarkB: Good point. I just did some brief testing and, for small values of `k`, using `std::partial_sort` can be significantly faster than `std::nth_element + std::sort`. For large `k` the two-step solution wins. Looks like something that needs to be profiled for GreyGeek's specific dataset.

Comment: someone knows a good reference that explains in details the complexity of std::nth_element ?

Comment: @GreyGeek: The C++ Standard just says "Linear on average".

Answer (score 7):

You might want to have a look at [partial_sort()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/partial_sort/)

It is both simple to understand and requires no extra work, and expected to be better [or at least not worse then] `sort()` if you only care for the kth element.

For optimal performance - you might want to use [selection algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm), but it requires more work.

Comment: Note that as the name implies, `std::partial_sort()` has to order elements preceding k'th element. Which is not necessary if only k'th element is of interest.

Answer (score 1):

### **First Algorithm:**

**Steps:**

- Use [Selection algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm) to find the k_th element.
- Choose it as a pivot and perform partition (from [quick sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) algorithm ) resulting in having the smallest k elements left to the pivot.

**Complexity:**
O(n) worst case

### **Second Algorithm:**

**Steps:**

- Use [make_heap](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/make_heap) to create heap out of the array elements.
- Perform k times the following:

  - read first element.
  - pop it using [pop_heap](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/pop_heap)

you could use [priorty queue](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue)'s methods ([c'tor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue/priority_queue), [top](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue/top), [pop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue/pop)) to achieve the same woithout knowing the algorithm lying behind.

**Complexity:**
O(n+ k * log(n)) worst case